# Проблемы с кодировкой(Передача данных по ссылке)

Tags: php, java, android, mysql, кодировка

С android устройства передаются значение на сайт через ссылку, русские заменяются на ??? и заносятся в бд тоже ???, как можно исправить, чтоб можно было и русские значения передавать?

Код отправки данных с андроида:

```
find_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 { 
@Override public void onClick(View v)
 { 
login_txt_find = find_txt.getText().toString();
 find_txt.setText("");
 full_url = url_regAcc+"login="+login_txt_find; 
new Show().execute(); 
} 

});

public class Show extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(full_url);
            Scanner in = new Scanner((InputStream) url.getContent());
            result = in.nextLine();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = e.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);
        try {
            if(Objects.equals(result, "7")) //Не подходит
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage(R.string.java_find_txt1)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.java_find_txt2, null);
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }else {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                login_prof_txt = jObject.getString("login");
                name_prof_txt = jObject.getString("name");
                surname_prof_txt = jObject.getString("surname");
                age_prof_txt = jObject.getString("age");
                city_prof_txt = jObject.getString("city");
                country_prof_txt = jObject.getString("country");

                String login_string = getString(R.string.java_string_login);
                String age_string = getString(R.string.java_string_age);
                info_login = login_string+login_prof_txt;
                info_name_surname = name_prof_txt+" "+surname_prof_txt;
                info_age = age_string+age_prof_txt;
                info_city = city_prof_txt;
                info_country = country_prof_txt;

                show_user();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну... Надо кодировки исправить. Но где - мы не знаем, т.к. вы код, те его места где кодировки указаны не показываете.

Comment: Ну, а где её вообще выставлять в android?в .htaccess UTF-8, в NotePad UTF-8, В БД utf-8 general ci

Comment: Я в этом мало понимаю, но у меня похожая проблема решилась тем, что в php скрипте кодировку соединения с БД через PDO надо было писать без тире, т.е. `UTF8`, вместо `utf-8`

Comment: А в андроиде, вроде, по умолчанию `utf-16` стоит и автоматом преобразуется в `utf-8`. Засим, думаю, проблема не на стороне андроида.

Comment: И да - попробуйте `UTF8_unicode_ci` вместо `general` для БД проставить

Comment: На разных устройствах по разному, на одном передается - на другом нет

Comment: Тогда покажите код коим в андроиде данные отправляете

Comment: Смена на utf8 unicode ci в БД не помогло

Comment: Показывайте код редактируя вопрос. Не надо в комменты. И покажите что у вас в `Show`

Answer (score 1):

Для указания кодировки надо указать в параметрах конструктора:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File, java.lang.String)

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner((InputStream) url.getContent(), "UTF-8");
```

Но вообще крайне рекомендую пользоваться okhttp, ну или [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)